# Attaching an Item to Survey List?

Tags: survey-list, attachments, list

I was planning on giving user an option to upload files while answering a survey. Is it possible to attach an item to a survey list ?

Thanks
Joe

Comment: The way Survey lists are designed, they are not as customizable as other lists. You would have to modify the content type to get the functionality you want, or use custom coding. This is probably overkill to meet your requirement. I think David's answer would work, you would have to make the custom list resemble a survey list.

Answer (score 2):

if not, use a custom list ;)

Answer (score 2):

This may not be an ideal answer; but since surveys are not easily customizable, and a custom list doesn't behave exactly like a survey, you might try this:

1. Create your survey.
2. Create a document library for user documents, and filter the library to only show the user their own documents.
3. Instruct the users to upload their docs to the library after completing the survey.
4. Create a page with a CEWP showing instructions, and a link to the survey and a link/view of the library.

Answer (score 1):

I used a multiline field, selected Enhanced Rich text and named it Screenshots for Question 1. Responders can attached and/or upload attachments (including images).

Comment: I like this option, however it doesn't leave the documents anonymous which is probably why they are looking to use the survey template to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a lookup column to survey that fetches docs in doc library.  Include the survey response number - or other unique survey response identifier - in the doc title.  But then a case of scrolling through the small lookup display (on the survey response edit form) to select matching document

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint 2013, you can select the External Data type to specify what types of files you want to upload when you create each question.  The hitch is that your administrator has to have enabled External Content Types or you will not have permissions to create an upload feature as part of the survey.

Comment: Considering this question was created in 2011, any references to SP2013 are not really valid.

Comment: Someone looking for this answer now might find this a valid/helpful answer even if the 3 years ago, nonexistent OP doesn't.